# Riemann sum calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find out the sum of the following series
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{n^2}{{(n^2+1)}^{3/2}} + \frac{n^2}{{(n^2+2)}^{3/2}} + \dots + \frac{n^2}{{(n^2+(n+1)^2)}^{3/2}}\right]
$$
now it would be just upto $n$ then I could have calculate with Riemann's integral by narrowing it and simplify then just integrate the definite integration. As it's upto $n+1$, I am having the trouble simplifying it. Any help?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your calculation. How did you reach to this sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $n+1$ terms, and all but the last are at least $1/2$.  So...

Comment: What is the limit of $\dfrac{n+1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: But maybe the real question was supposed to have $n$ instead of $n^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, there are $(n+1)^2$ terms, as I see.

Comment: Good point.  So to get a nontrivial limit, you want $1$ in the numerator.

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake, the denominator is (n^2+(n+1)^2)^3/2

Comment: @TamimAdDari,but 2nd one is 2 or 4?

Comment: Expanding on this answer, see: the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test).